# - hexadecimal number answer for 24

Tags: binary

Noob question but wanted to know if my answer was correct.
What is the **16-bit hexadecimal** representation of each of the following signed decimal integer? 
–24
Answer: 11101000

Comment: Um... Windows Calc can answer this question for you. What do you need from us in addition to that information?

Comment: I waned to know if I needed to convert those numbers back into Hex form. I was thinking that I needed to split it up in 4 then add the numbers/letters.

Comment: Your answer (whether correct or not) seems to be in binary, not hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks Gserg! now i know that i have to convert it to Hex. Thanks aswell Ken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Windows Calculator for that.  Do "View/Programmer"
You can change it to "byte" mode for an 8 bit value.  And "Dec" mode.  Type in your number -24, and as you saw the bits are 1110 1000.

1110 = E,
1000 = 8

You can press the "Hex" option to switch, and you'll see the E8.